# Go method parameter and float64 array giving unexpected errors

Tags: go

When compiling the following code...

```
package camera

type camera struct {
    position [3]float64
    viewWidth int
    viewHeight int
}

func (c camera) SwitchToCartesianThreeSpace(x, y int) [3]float64 { // LINE 9
    var x3 float64 = 0 // view is set to the origin
    var y3 float64 = float64(x) - (float64(c.viewWidth) / 2)
    var z3 float64 = float64(-y) + (float64(c.viewHeight) / 2)
    result := [3]float64{x3, y3, z3}                               // LINE 13
    return result
}
```

...the following errors occur.

```
camera/camera.go:9: undefined: x
camera/camera.go:9: undefined: y
camera/camera.go:11: undefined: x
camera/camera.go:12: undefined: y
camera/camera.go:13: cannot use x3 (type float64) as type [3]float64 in array element
camera/camera.go:13: cannot use y3 (type float64) as type [3]float64 in array element
camera/camera.go:13: cannot use z3 (type float64) as type [3]float64 in array element
```

I've written a fair amount of Go code so far and do not understand why the errors on line 9 or the errors on line 13 are occurring! Anyone able to explain?

Comment: Yet, this (http://play.golang.org/p/zL9oZvHRDh) compile just fine...

Comment: Ever strange. Looks to be a problem with the package structure... Thanks for confirming my sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isolating [in a playgroud](http://play.golang.org/p/a9dP5Pe2RO), it compiles just fine, and has the expected output:

```
c := camera{}
res := c.SwitchToCartesianThreeSpace(2, 3)
// res is [0 2 -3]
```

You need to try with a `camera.go` including *only* that code, or check how the `camera.go` file fits in your [current workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces).